# Trigger Lifecyclehooks of NUXT/VUE at static generated pages

Tags: vue.js, static, reload, lifecycle, nuxt.js

I tried to trigger the lifecyclehooks of NUXT or VUE, at the static generated (per `npm run generate`) page.
Every time I enter the page directly per link or reload the page the Lifecyclehooks aren't triggered.

Do you have any advice how I can force the wanted behavior?

### If you need more Information please let me know what you need...

My last try before I changed to a router middleware was the mounted hook:

```
mounted() {
 this.$store.commit('setPlans', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('prices')))
 this.$axios.get('/prices').then(resp => {
 this.$store.commit('setPlans', resp.data)
    localStorage.setItem('prices', JSON.stringify(resp.data))
 })
},
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you tried to create these hooks?

Comment: I added my last try to the question...